# how to find complex css selector

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors

i want to fill text in selenium firefox broswer 
how to find entering text selector its very complex for me please explain me the only way i want to achieve this using only css selector

```
<div class="Gb WK">
 <div class="Rd"guidedhelpid="sharebox_editor">
<div class="eg">
     <div class="yw oo"">
<div class="yw vk"">
    </div>
    <div class="URaP8 Kf Pf b-K b-K-Xb">
      <div id="195" class="pq"
          Share what's new...
           </div>
           <div id=":37.f" class="df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable"     contenteditable="true"
            g_editable="true"role="textbox"aria-labelledby="195"></div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Tell us which `tag` you want to identify and what you have tried?

Comment: i want fill [role="textbox]

Answer (score 1):

You already wrote the `cssSelector`. However I will explain this for you. `CssSelector` allows you to use single/multiple attribute search. In case if you don't find a single attribute unique you can keep adding more attribute to the selector

Single attribute

```
[role='textbox']
```

Multiple attributes

```
[role='textbox'][contenteditable='true']
```

If you want to add div for a faster search that's possible too

```
div[role='textbox'][contenteditable='true']
```

Notice if I don't add `div` it's going to be tag independent search

Comment: no not working for me its googleplus page u can see the real source there is any other way that find selector like class selector

Comment: I am totally lost what you are trying to do. First, you really have to tell me what does **not working means** like something with StackTrace or some kind of proof and what's happening. Second, if there is any other way you have to tell me what it is. There is no other way to write cssselector as per my knowledge. And, You said this is not real source what does that mean? If that's the case why you want to automate soemthing you don't have control over?

Comment: no ,this is real source its not finding selector ,i said i want to automate my google plus page ,i m getting element cant find error

Comment: Selenium drivers the browser and in order to do that you don't need real source you need client side page which you already have. You are probably facing wait issue. Provide screenshot if possible, more html and test code in order for us to help you

Comment: i m not using selenuim drivers, im using python`s ghost.py  both work on css selector ,i put my time limit up 120 sec